# Trying to make synaptics work on Fedora 25

Tags: fedora, xorg, synaptics-touchpad

I'm trying to make Synaptics work for my trackpad (more specially the Magic Trackpad 2, but this is an other matter).

For now, libinput is taking the command of the trackpad, and for that specific trackpad, I'd like Synaptics to be the master in command.

So here's what I tried :

I've created a 50-magictrackpad.conf on the /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/ folder, containing the following :

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Apple Magic Trackpad"
    Driver "synaptics"

    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchProduct "Apple"
EndSection
```

Note that I'm trying to match the product "Apple" for specifically getting the Magic Trackpad 2.

After a reboot, it doesn't seems to work, when calling `synclient` I get the following message :

```
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
```

Needless to say that I've installed the `xorg-x11-drv-synaptics` package before rebooting.

So I also tried the following (and rebooted each time), all without any luck :

1. Placed that file in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/
2. Copied the file in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf to /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/
3. Changed the priority number of 50-magictrackpad.conf to 49-magictrackpad.conf

Everytime, `synclient` tells me there is no Synaptics driver loaded.

What can I do? What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Wayland?

Comment: Apparently yes. I also discovered that the trackpad works really well under linux when it's the one connected at the Macbook pro. Apparently it's just a problem of identification made by libinput. I don't mind using libinput or synaptics, I just want the trackpad to work

Comment: You can chose to run without wayland, if you experience problems with that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40935697/fedora-android-studio-is-not-running/40951490#40951490
But even better would be to report the errors so they can be fixed in future releases.

Comment: Yes indeed, I've posted on the Kernel's bug, and I'll see what they say. If I ever made it work, I'll post here a solution.